# optimize.minimize with for loop - python, pandas

Tags: python, pandas, loops, optimization

I have a `target = 50` and `achieved = 44` a dataframe of input:

```
        Yearly_value    headroom     
2020         1             0
2021         2             0
2022         1             0
2023         3             4
2024         1             5
2025         1             6
```

I would like to optimize 1 list of variables (tuples?) x, y so that:

- `achieved + sum([ (x[year]*8760 + y[year]*3132) * df['Yearly_value'][year] for year in df.index]) = target`
- `x + y is as small as possible` because for each x and y I have to pay a price

Under the constraints:

- `[(x[year] + y[year]) <= headroom[year] for year in df.index]`
- `x >= 0 & y >= 0 for each x, y in list`

I was trying:

```
bnds=()
for year in [2020, 2021, 2022, 2023, 2024, 2025, 2026, 2027, 2028, 2029, 2030]:
    bound = (0, headroom[year]), (0, headroom[year])
    bnds= bnds + (bound,)

def diff(param):
    x, y= param
    return abs(target - achieved - sum(df['Yearly_value']*[x + y]))

x0 = [(1,1),(1,1),(1,1),(1,1),(1,1),(1,1)]

res = minimize(diff, x0, bounds=bnds)
```

I dont know how to include that x + y should be as small as possible and, I keep getting errors like:

`---> 18         x, y = param
      19         return abs(target - achieved - sum(df['Yearly_value']*[x + y]))
      20 ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

any help? thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your design vector (including the initial guess x0) should be a 1-dimensional vector. The error is coming from this. Rewrite it to `x0 = [1, 1, 1, ... 1]`

In your `diff` function you can get `x` and `y` as the even and odd elements from `param`.